# Postgres COPY error, export from heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, relational-database

I exported a dump file from a postgres db from heroku ([with the default export way](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)). The export was successful and I managed to import locally all the tables with some errors more or less, except from one table.

I separated the table that I couldn't import, it is a bunch of `COPY` sql commands which I tried to import it alone. Unfortunately it always throws syntax error. A part of the export goes like this:

`COPY "yachts" ("id", "user_id", "description", "per_day", "per_week", "security_fee", "cleaning_fee", "check_in_at", "check_out_at", "min_stay_days", "created_at", "updated_at", "year_manufactured", "registration_number", "registration_name", "currency", "longitude", "latitude", "published", "country", "rating", "marina", "zoom_level", "archived", "score", "score_adjustment", "crew_per_day", "location_id", "commission_percentage", "year_refitted", "locale", "crew_type", "included_in_price", "apa_fee", "per_weekend", "sent_script_to_linkwise", "read_only", "published_at", "test_boat", "handover_day", "lloyds_verified", "docs_verified", "location_name", "calendar_updated_at", "rate_to_euros", "created_by_id", "published_by_id", "crew_status", "position", "seasonal_pricing", "last_year_with_pricing", "crew_per_week", "listing_title", "locked", "cached_minimum_day_price_cents", "cached_maximum_day_price_cents", "type", "pier_location", "usage") FROM stdin;
1196  2743  Cabins 2\r\nBeds 4\r\nToilet 1\r\nShower 1\r\n\r\nDepth meter\r\nRudder position indicator\r\nGPS chart plotter\r\nBattery charger, transformer\r\nBow thruster\r\nStern thruster\r\nAnchor winch\r\nAnchor\r\nShore power\r\nGas cooker\r\nMicrowave + oven\r\nRefrigerator\r\nCoffee machine\r\nHeating\r\nWarm water via boiler\r\nCar radio + CD player\r\nTV + DVB-T + DVD player  213 \N  750 85  13:00:00  09:00:00  1 2013-12-13 16:32:19.657946  2015-07-10 10:26:06.327685  \N    Drait 82  EUR 12.424844 52.413048 f DE  \N  Marina Brandenburg-Plaue  12  f 4500  0 0 2945358 20.00 \N  en  \N  --- []\n  0 \N  t f 2013-12-13 16:32:19.657946  f \N  f f Brandenburg an der Havel  \N  1.00000 \N  \N  none  0101000020E6100000BCCD1B2785D92840D0D6C1C1DE344A40  t 2015  0 River boat in Bradenbourg f 21300 21300 MotorBoat \N  \N
\.`

For a better format I included this file with some more records https://ufile.io/6yecu

I tried with `psql` and `pg_restore` but it seems to me that the records are causing problems due to many escape characters. Can I do something to import this one or is it lost? Unfortunately I don't have access to DB to export again.

**UPDATE:**
Seems during the splitting that I corrupted the tabs of the file as correctly mentioned in the comments from Jasen. I am trying to import the original file with this command:

`psql new_database < backup_db`

and I am getting many errors: https://ufile.io/aozf7

Comment: with psql what's the error message?

Comment: It displays this: 
`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1196  2743  Cabins 2 ... "`

Comment: Your file has been corrupted, there should be TAB characters beetween values. not spaces.